# Kaltura Bulk Upload CSV

Tags: csv, upload, bulk, kaltura

I want to use Kaltura Bulk Upload Entries CSV to upload a batch of videos from an ftp server.
However I could not find any documentation on the Usage and Schema Description for **Entries CSV**

Particularly I am looking for a document similar to **[this one](http://knowledge.kaltura.com/end-users-csv-usage-and-schema-description#csv)**, which presents the parameters and their usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the KMC (Kaltura Management Console) > Upload > "Download CSV/XML Samples". Link below:
http://www.kaltura.com/content/docs/kaltura_batch_upload_falcon.zip

And this video tutorial:
http://videos.kaltura.com/media/Bulk+Upload+Using+CSV+or+XML+%7C+Kaltura+Video+Tutorial/1_kxiv585x

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have already found the links you mentioned. What I am trying to do is understand the individual entries and what they do (so that I can determine which ones I want to use). I thought something like the link mentioned in my question (for entries csv) would be really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

The Kaltura Bulk Upload schema can be found here: http://www.kaltura.com/api_v3/xsdDoc/?type=bulkUploadXml.bulkUploadXML